# Copy one element of string array into another java

Tags: java, arrays, csv

Hi I'm essentially trying to copy an element of one array into another array. I have the array lineOfData which holds data from a csv file (id, size, custom label) and I want a new array ids that just holds the ids. I have tried ids = lineOfData[0]; but to no avail. what is the best way to do this?

```
Code:
public class Merge {
String filePath;

public Merge()  {

}


public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Frame myFrame = new Frame();
    FileDialog fileBox = new FileDialog(myFrame, "Open", FileDialog.LOAD);
    fileBox.setVisible(true);
    String filename = fileBox.getFile();
    String directoryPath = fileBox.getDirectory();
    if ( filename !=null )
    {
        String filePath = directoryPath + filename;
        //testFile(filePath);
        mergeFile(filePath);
    }
}

public static void mergeFile(String... filePaths) throws FileNotFoundException {
    String[] lineOfData = null;
    String[] ids = null;

    for(String filePath : filePaths)
    {
        String path = filePath;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(path));
        String columnTitle = scanner.nextLine();
        while(scanner.hasNextLine())
        {
            //scanner.useDelimiter(",");
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            lineOfData = line.split(",");
            ids[0] = lineOfData[0];
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ids));
            }
        scanner.close();
    }


}
```

Comment: Post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned that you're getting that "The value ids can only be null at this location". This is because you haven't initialized the ids array. Right now, ids isn't pointing to any array. In order to fix this, you

```
String line = scanner.nextLine();
lineOfData = line.split(",");
ids = new String[lineOfData.length];
ids[0] = lineOfData[0];
```

if you're going to be adding all the values of `lineOfData` to `ids`, or

```
String line = scanner.nextLine();
lineOfData = line.split(",");
ids = new String[1];
ids[0] = lineOfData[0];
```

if you only want to copy one element of `lineOfData` into `ids`.

Also, notice that `lineOfData` also starts out by not pointing to any array. However, the `lineOfData = line.split(",");` line fixes that, and makes it point to an array of Strings. Ask if you have any questions.

Comment: This is giving a null pointer exception? "The variable ids can only be null at this location"

Comment: Could you post the code for you class? I don't see that error when i use your method

Comment: I did but it won't affect the score as my rep is too low, sorry.